# Using Random number generation function in python

Tags: python-3.x

Is there any way we can generate two random numbers that would satisfy the following condition:
`18.5 <= num_1 / num_2**2 < 25` i.e this expression returns true.

Comment: Yes, there is...

Comment: Look at the [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module functions, i.e. randint()

Answer (score 0):

There you go (2 random integers):

```
import random
import math

MAX_NUM_2 = 100
num_2 = random.randrange(1, MAX_NUM_2 + 1)
num_1 = random.randrange(math.ceil(num_2 ** 2 * 18.5), num_2 ** 2 * 25)
```

Comment: This wouldn't generate the two intended numbers. I am asking that generate two random numbers that when we put these two numbers in the given equation it returns true.

Comment: @Waqar: Have you tried it? Do you have a counterexample of two numbers that this code generates and do not satisfy the given equation???